# The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.) when try to get the details with an ID

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

I have integrated facebook iOS SDK 3.1, which supports for iOS6, so I could able to get all queries with facebook without any issue, but sometimes when I query to get the details of an event with its ID, It is giving following error:

HTTP status code: 400
The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)

When I logout and login again, its working perfectly, but I dont want users to get frustration by doing this when this type of error occured.

I have been verifying the issue's cause but no luck as it is not reproducing constantly.

Thanks in advance for your valuable clue on the issue.

Comment: Does it happen only when you authenticate with iOS6 native settings or even when authenticating with the Facebook app or m-site? It might be because of an invalid token getting returned.

Comment: Not sure, as I received feedback from users and it was not reproduced certainly but I am sure the issue was there as I received the same issue from multiple users. For temporary fix, when the error occurred, will be showing an alert to users by asking them to logout and login again.

Comment: Have you raised it on Facebook Developers Support?

Comment: There are a few reasons that can fire the error 5. It could be because you're making a request without having a opened session. Are you making sure the session is open before firing the request? Also, you may be firing multiple requests at the same time or even processing one while firing another one? But it really looks like not opened session.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState)state
                      error:(NSError *)error
{    switch (state) {
        case FBSessionStateOpen: {
            [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
             ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
               NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
               NSError *error) {
                 if (error) {
                     //error
                 }else{
                     NSString *email=[user objectForKey:@"email"];
                     NSString *name=[user objectForKey:@"name"];

                     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"Loginwithfacebook" object: [NSArray arrayWithObjects:email,name, nil]];
                 }
             }];

                   }
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed: {
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            }
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed: {
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```